# C# Protobuf project fails to build in Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, protocol-buffers

I have a solution containing a protobuf definition file as a class library, and a gRPC service referencing the protobuf definition file. It's tied together with a solution file in the root folder.

If I build the project on my Windows machine, there's no issue:

```
$ dotnet build "GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj" -c Release -o build
MSBuild version 17.5.0+6f08c67f3 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored ...\DockerTest\GrpcService\GrpcService.csproj (in 131 ms).
  GrpcService -> ...\DockerTest\build\GrpcService.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.14
```

After building I'm able to start the gRPC service with the command `dotnet .\build\GrpcService.dll`.

After that I'm trying to get my solution to build inside a Docker container. I've created a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0.203-alpine3.17 AS build

WORKDIR /src

COPY DockerTest.sln ./
COPY Test.Grpc/*.csproj ./Test.Grpc/
COPY GrpcService/*.csproj ./GrpcService/

RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .

RUN dotnet build "GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish/backend
```

And when I try to build the project inside a Docker container, the build fails because the proto builder can't find `/src/GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj`.

```
$ docker build .
[+] Building 47.8s (12/12) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0.203-alpine3.17                                   0.5s
 => [1/8] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0.203-alpine3.17@sha256:626f01d39214df0611f7e4a29083447dbeb80b5f42e  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2.10kB                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [2/8] WORKDIR /src                                                                                      0.0s
 => [3/8] COPY DockerTest.sln ./                                                                                   0.1s
 => [4/8] COPY Test.Grpc/*.csproj ./Test.Grpc/                                                                     0.1s
 => [5/8] COPY GrpcService/*.csproj ./GrpcService/                                                                 0.1s
 => [6/8] RUN dotnet restore                                                                                      43.9s
 => [7/8] COPY . .                                                                                                 1.1s
 => ERROR [8/8] RUN dotnet build "GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish/backend               1.9s
------
 > [8/8] RUN dotnet build "GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish/backend:
#12 0.499 MSBuild version 17.5.1+f6fdcf537 for .NET
#12 0.986   Determining projects to restore...
#12 1.493   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
#12 1.814 /root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/build/_protobuf/Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "/root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/tools/linux_x64/protoc" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): An error occurred trying to start process '/root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/tools/linux_x64/protoc' with working directory '/src/GrpcService'. No such file or directory [/src/GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj]
#12 1.814 /root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/build/_protobuf/Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec) [/src/GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj]
#12 1.814 /root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/build/_protobuf/Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [/src/GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj]
#12 1.814 /root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/build/_protobuf/Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [/src/GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj]
#12 1.814 /root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/build/_protobuf/Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [/src/GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj]
#12 1.821
#12 1.821 Build FAILED.
#12 1.821
#12 1.821 /root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/build/_protobuf/Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "/root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/tools/linux_x64/protoc" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): An error occurred trying to start process '/root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/tools/linux_x64/protoc' with working directory '/src/GrpcService'. No such file or directory [/src/GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj]
#12 1.821 /root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/build/_protobuf/Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec) [/src/GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj]
#12 1.821 /root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/build/_protobuf/Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [/src/GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj]
#12 1.821 /root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/build/_protobuf/Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [/src/GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj]
#12 1.821 /root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.49.0/build/_protobuf/Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [/src/GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj]
#12 1.821     0 Warning(s)
#12 1.821     1 Error(s)
#12 1.821
#12 1.821 Time Elapsed 00:00:01.13
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet build "GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish/backend]: exit code: 1
```

But if I remove the last instruction from the Dockerfile, create a container and dump the contents from the container to see how it looks, the file is clearly there.

`docker export -o dump.tar [container-id]`

So what is going wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128227/cannot-run-grpc-protoc-in-alpine-based-dotnet-sdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ran into the same issue. For those who might encounter this in the future, the error stems from the Alpine Docker image lacking certain tools that ***grpc.tools*** needs. You can resolve this by installing the necessary tools directly into the Alpine image. Here's how:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0.203-alpine3.17 AS build
    RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
    # ... rest of your Dockerfile ...
```